# Comma inside \texttt{} does’nt show up

Tags: viewers, typewriter

I am trying to print a comma inside a `\texttt{}` tag, but it is not printing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \texttt{foo, bar}  
\end{document}
```

produces:

```
foo bar
```

not

```
foo, bar
```

How to print the comma inside without loading extra packages, though defining new command is allowed?

---

I have TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012) kpathsea version 6.1.0

I use the command `\ll` to compile and `\lv` to view from Vim using the Vim-LaTeX plugin. The viewer is Document Viewer 3.6.0

The `\ll` command calls the TeX compiler using this command:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

The log file is located here: http://pastebin.com/JKJBk7xv

Comment: I can see the comma on my system without any issue.

Comment: It should produce a comma, something is seriously wrong with your setuo if not. What does the log say when you run that?

Comment: It works correctly with me. The problem must be with your LaTeX. Do you have the latest versions?

Comment: Which TeX compiler, which output format, which viewer?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing a comma and not the character "‚" Unicode SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201A)?

Comment: @egreg at least the one in the MWE is a comma

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but if I try U+201A in place of that comma, I get no output from it and "There is no <E2> in font cmtt10" and similarly for `<80>` and `<9A>`.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; I'm inclined to bet you'll see `âĂŽ` in place of the disappearing commas.

Comment: Yes It's a good call, if the OP shows the log file and that's the reason you get the [tag:crystall-ball] badge again

Comment: The log linked to cannot come from the example given above: many more packages loaded!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was apparently the Document Viewer 3.6.0

I installed Okular, made it default dvi viewer and suddenly the commas show. Apparently it is a bug in Document Viewer.

Comment: Make a bug report to the guys who develop Document Viewer, ok?