# How do I get my comma back (C++ lstlisting section)

Tags: listings, programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma inside \texttt{} does’nt show up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84711/comma-inside-texttt-doesnt-show-up)

I've been writing code in my book and just noticed that the comma has gone. I've been moving between machines so I don't know if this is just a setup issue, or I've not ever had commas.

my listing setup:

```
\lstset{ %
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep=15pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    tabsize=2,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    title=\lstname,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
}
```

and it's not showing commas in a variable declaration:

```
int a, b, c, d;
```

Comment: With this settings, the commas were shown when I tested it. It would be good if you would complete your code snippet to a small compilable example which shows the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)
 Please, check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84711/comma-inside-texttt-doesnt-show-up): it may only be a previewer problem

Comment: Indeed it was, many thanks. I will just remember to preview as a PDF rather than DVI from now on.